# SQLite on Flash don't work?

Tags: android, mobile, air, flash-cs6

I'm working in a Flash project to Mobile (Android/iOs), and I'm confused about the SQLite on Flash. I'm not using FLEX! I'm using only Flash Professional CS6. I am trying use:

```
import flash.data.SQLResult;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.data.SQLStatement;
import flash.data.SQLConnection;
import flash.data.SQLColumnSchema;
import flash.data.SQLTableSchema;
import flash.data.SQLSchemaResult;
import flash.events.SQLEvent;
import flash.events.SQLErrorEvent;
```

But All have returned error: "-The import File could not be found." Not exist "flash.data.*" in Flash Professional Project ???? How I use SQLite with Flash Project??

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

In the Properties panel, set the Target to "AIR 3.x for iOS" or "AIR 3.x for Android"

Comment: sorry...this question is very old and I already solve this problem... I  threw the flash in trash and now I work with phonegap.